# Onclick change attribute value

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to change the value of input type submit onclick. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("main-add-to-cart");

$('.main-add-to-cart').on('click', function() {
  if (elem.value == "Add to cart") {
    elem.value = "New Changed text";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="main-add-to-cart form-submit ajax-processed" type="submit" id="edit-submit--3346" name="op" value="Add to cart">
```

Thank you.

Comment: `var elem = document.querySelector(".main-add-to-cart");`

Comment: Or just `this.value = ...`

Comment: @doodlemeister : Why my line of code didn't work? Your's is working by the way.

Comment: Because `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, so it doesn't have a `value` property. That's just on individual elements. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DOM selection using `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, so it doesn't have a `.value` property.

You could instead select the first element with that class using `.querySelector()`.

```
var elem = document.querySelector(".main-add-to-cart");
```

---

However, the bound element is available in the handler via `this`, so you don't really need the variable.

```
if (this.value == "Add to cart") {
  this.value = "New Changed text";
}
```

---

And in general, here's a non-jQuery solution.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".main-add-to-cart");

elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.value == "Add to cart") {
    this.value = "New Changed text";
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="main-add-to-cart form-submit ajax-processed" type="submit" id="edit-submit--3346" name="op" value="Add to cart">
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like structure, and not a single value.

Assuming that there's only one element, you can correct your code like the following to make it work:

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("main-add-to-cart")[0];

$('.main-add-to-cart').on('click', function() {
  if (elem.value == "Add to cart") {
    elem.value = "New Changed text";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="main-add-to-cart form-submit ajax-processed" type="submit" id="edit-submit--3346" name="op" value="Add to cart">
```

Notice that I've used `[0]` to get the first element from the selector's result. If you've more than one elements, you need to loop through the result and check your condition(s).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#edit-submit--3346').click(function(){

    if($(this).val() == 'Add to cart')
        $(this).val('New Changed text');

    $('#form').submit();
})
```

Comment: Its my pleasure! Good Luck!